# Como pegar o "Base Address" do módulo principal de um outro processo

Tags: c#

Ola, eu fiz um software que Analisa o dump de um processo de certa Engine  para extrair a chave do XOR do jogo automaticamente pois o mesmo tem uma XOR de 16 bytes dinâmica mudando de compilação pra compilação do jogo... E para traduzir jogos dessa engine preciso descriptografar seus arquivos.

Atualmente eu analizo um dump feito pelo ProcessDump e o mesmo ao dumpar um processo deixa no nome do arquivo o "Base Address" do módulo dumpado.

Eu queria saber como eu podeira no C# uma forma compatível com x86 e x64 de pegar o "Base Address" de um processo sem ter que dumpa-lo... afinal a class Process não consegue dizer para mim o Base Address, sempre crasha quando tento.

Fiquei sabendo ontem de uma Biblioteca chamada de MemorySharp, será que ela deve ser útil ao meu caso?

PS: Aceito P/Invoke

Comment: Você já tentou usar o [`GetModuleHandle`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetModuleHandle.html?diff=y)?

Comment: Queria poder distinguir processos do mesmo nome, se possível especificar o PID dele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("meuPrograma"); 
Process mProc = processes[0]; 
IntPtr hProc = mProc.Handle; 

int base_adr = processes[0].MainModule.EntryPointAddress.ToInt32(); 
int height_offset = 0x0007E1BC; 
height_adr = (IntPtr)(base_adr + height_offset); 

ckFreezeFlag.Text = "Base: " + base_adr.ToString("X"); 
ckFreezeMines.Text = "Height: " + height_adr.ToString("X");
```

Tenha em mente que a chamada  mProc = processes[0];  pode não ter um resultado preenchido, logo pode provocar um erro, você deve testar se está vazio.

O offset é por sua conta ;)

Comment: ja tentei utilizar esse recurso do Process, acontece que o processo não retorna nenhum módulo...

Comment: Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("meuPrograma");  Está retornando algum processo no Array?

Comment: Sim, este é o erro:
http://image.prntscr.com/image/8dbcbad72cd9409fa0b2950097c8a7d1.jpeg

Comment: A imagem cortou o texto da Exception e não dá pra ler o erro todo, pode ser algo de permissão para rodar esse código.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/CuC9TYf1`
Ja tentei compilar meu programa em 32bits, 64 e Any CPU...
Minha maquina é 64, OS também... mas o processo que quero analizar geralmente é 32bits.
E já executei como administrador meu programa.

Comment: Esqueci de comentar, mas o código funciona, acontece que na epoca eu estava apenas usando uma build do executável com certa DRM que protegia a listagem dos módulos, quando descobri bastou desligar o recurso e funcionou.